# Confirm or deny that combinations of numbers with the same sum exist in a set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm trying to find a universal formula for a case when:

- I have a certain number of kinds of items like pens, oranges, credit
  cards (integer, >=2).
- All of these items have a common property like weight (decimal, >0).
- There are at least 0 items of each type in the set (8 pencils, 1 credit card, 0 oranges)

There is a need to confirm or deny that any combinations of these items have the same sum.

An example of such overlap would be:

- Penсil weighs 5 grams, credit card weighs 10 grams. 2 pencils = 1 credit card, overlap exists.
- Pen weighs 3.5 grams, credit card weighs 10 grams. 20 pens = 7 credit cards, combination exists.
- USB stick weighs 12.7 grams, bottle of oil weighs 3.25 grams, credit card is 10 grams. 5 USB sticks + 2 bottles of oil = 7 credit cards, combination exists.

Not all items must participate in the evaluation, having at least one combination is enough. No matter how you combine/permutate items and their amounts it's important to have a mathematical proof that such overlaps exist/don't exist. It's also acceptable to limit the amount of each item type (e.g. <=1000 pencils in a set instead of <=∞ pencils) if it makes solving this kind of problem easier.

Comment: If the ratio of any two weights is rational, a combination involving just those two is possible. Are you going to have irrational weights?

Comment: No, weights are decimal and rational

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It looks more like a programming challenge than a math question.

Comment: Then if one weight is $w=p/q$, and another is $v=r/s$, you'll have $qrw=psv$, as both will be $pr$.

Comment: Does that answer your question, HardLuck?

Comment: partially, yes, i'm still interested in boundaries when i can make sure such collisions don't exist and a formula to find them.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "boundaries". Collisions always exist when the weights are rational, and my comment gives a formula that always finds one. Please clarify what you want. Also, if you want to ensure that I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.